# Getting text value of radio instead with the actual value in ko.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an ko.js app and I stumbled upon a few troubles. 
It is simple to make observable the value of selected radio with checked binding,
But how does one get the text of the following element? Here is what I'm talking about.

```
<input type="radio" value="323" data-bind="checked: foodId">
<span data-bind="text:foodName"></span>
```

So I need to get the name of entry from the span, not its actual ID. Here is what is needed in the end after the user makes his choice.

```
<p>you have selected hamburger</p>
```

But with ko.js it only seems possible to get the value of radio, but showing message you have selected "323" is not what I need. I think jquery could help, but I've heard using jquery event listeners with ko.js is not recommended.

Edit: 
The data looks something like this,

```
var viewModel = function(){

    this.food = ko.observableArray([{foodId: 323, foodName:'hamburger'},
                                    {foodId: 339, foodName:'pizza'}]
}
```

In the HTML, I use foreach binding to display all entries. 
I'm sorry i can't copy the full code, I'm on mobile and have no source currently.

Could you help me with it?

Comment: Can you post the viewmodel of the object that contains the foodName property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add something to hold the selected value in your view model. Then call a function like the `selectedFoodName` function I added in order to get the current selected food's name.

```
// untested but should help you get the idea
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedFoodId = ko.observable();
    self.food = ko.observableArray([{foodId: 323, foodName:'hamburger'},
                                {foodId: 339, foodName:'pizza'}]);

    self.selectedFoodName = ko.computed(function() {
        var food = self.food();
        var selectedFoodId = self.selectedFoodId();

        for (var i = 0, len = food.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (food[i].foodId === selectedFoodId) {
                return food[i].foodName;
            }
        }
        return "None";
    }, self);
};
```

Then in your html:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: food">
    <input type="radio" data-bind="value: foodId, checked: selectedFoodId" />
    <span data-bind="text: foodName"></span>
</div>
<div>Your selected food is: <span data-bind="text: selectedFoodName"></span></div>
```

Comment: If you're really lazy you could just do something like: `<input type="radio" data-bind="value: foodName, checked: selectedFoodName" />`... then change `selectedFoodName` to an observable and delete `selectedFoodId`. Whenever I do something like this I always store the ID then reference the object by its ID (makes it easier for when I want to post a value to the server).